# In Excel how 2 have cells A1, 2, 3 etc reference a single formula that corresponds 2 other cells in say columns B & C in relation 2 cells A1, 2, 3 etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the formula to say for ex. B1+C1 for A1, and for A2, B2+C2, A3, B3+C3.

I'm trying to go this so I only have to write the formula once. I've just discovered the r1c1 reference style but haven't figured out how to do it if it's possible.

Anyone know how I can do this any possible way? Thanks

Comment: removed excel-vba tag since this has nothing to do with VBA

Comment: maybe you can use drag with mouse? I'm not sure if this is your problem, but if you write a formula in ex. A1 (`=B1+C1`) and move to the bottom line of A1 cell, the cursor will change, than you drag bottom direction, it will create what you want

Comment: This method is generally used to aid VBA programming, therefore I understand why the tag was there.

Answer (score 1):

Select cell A1 and use

```
=B1&C1
```

Then highlight the cell, click and hold the right corner and drag down

Comment: Yes. There is no way to just enter the formula once for all rows and have it autofill for the row.

Comment: Well someone suggested "indirect" function, which got me into r1c1, and not sure if one or both did it but I was able to accomplish part of this, just without the formula. I had cells down A referring to a cell elsewhere which referred back to cells in column B, of rows corresponding to those in column A. The values in B were simply 1,2,3, the numbers of the rows, and the cells in A were the same, all by referring to one cell elsewhere which directed those under A back to B. Again there were no formulas. So... Idk. I guess not.

Comment: Ah ok, apologies. I would reccommend using r1c1 reference style infact. Anyway the formula to use this is simple, for example `=RC[-2] + RC[-1]` would add the values from the 2 cells to the left. Replace the number in the " [ ] " to correspond with the data you want to use. Using a negative number offsets the cell to the left and positive to the right. Place the "C" to the other side e.g. `=R[-2]C + RC[1]` to offset the cells vertically. `=R [-1]C to go up =R[1]C` to go down. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the formula down/accross to duplicate and work along whole columns/rows

[image]